# Auto number field with variable prefix

Tags: lightning, admin

I'm looking at adding a unique identifier field for my assets that will have a prefix of the record type and then a following 4 numbers.

- Office Equipment

  - Abbreviation of OE
- Remote Equipment

  - Abbreviation of RE

So we would have **OE-0001** and **RE-0001** as two unique records, in the same field, same record.

I know we can use something like **A-{0000}** to specify **A** as the prefix and **{0000}** as the minimum numbers to show. But replacing the **A** is the issue?

Can this be done / how?

Comment: How does this have anything to do with [tag:lightning]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am sorry this cannot be done with the standard salesforce Autonumber functionality. You have to do some hacks to achieve this.

1. Convert the name field from  Autonumber to Text
2. Create a new Autonumber Field
3. Create a WF rule on created, Add a field update to update Name field.

   If(RecordType=='Bla','RE-'+AutoNumberFiled__C,'BE-'+AutoNumberFiled__C)